# How to restrict "0" should not be placed at the first character in the text box with jquery how can i do

Tags: jquery, html

i want to restrict "0" should not be placed at the first character in the text box.

```
<div class="form-group row" align="center">
  <label class="col-md-4 form-control-label"><span class="mandatory"></span> Payment</label>
   <div class="col-md-8" >
      <div class="input-group">
        <input  type="text"  name="pay" id= "pay" class="form-control input-md" max="100000"/>
      </div>
  </div>
</div> 

var myLength = $("#pay").val().length;          
if($(this).val() === '0')
{               
   $(this).val('');
}
```

It restrict the first digit '0' but multiple 0's allowing and another scenario is first i enter `10` after i entered 0's before `00010`.

I want only start without `0`.

Comment: @check my answer and fiddle link will solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check it by `charAt` function if it string:

```
var myLength = $("#pay").val();

        if(myLength.charAt(0) === '0')
        {               
            $(this).val('');
        }
```

More useful way for the input box not to accept 0 as first place.

Check Working Code: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sagar_arora/Lqxaxpt1/)

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use `keyup` event to prevent typing `0` in the first position while user is typing.

Here's a **Demo:**

```js
$('#pay').keyup(function(e){
      if($(this).val().match(/^0/)){
          $(this).val('');
          return false;
      }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input  type="text"  name="pay" id= "pay" class="form-control input-md" max="100000"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

To match a number starting with any digit but not zero, use this regex:

```
^[1-9][0-9]*$
```

Ex:

```
function validateInput(input) {
   var regex = ^[1-9][0-9]*$;
   return regex.test(input);  // It will return true or false depends on the regex test
}
```

call this function with your input value.